# Why doesn't pyrogram see the chat description?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

pyrogram doesn't see the chat description

I write to my chat with a description and

```
@app.on_message()
async def handler(_, msg: types.Message):
    print(msg.chat.bio)
    print(msg.chat.description)
```

this /\ outputs this \/

```
None
None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Chat` object within the `Message` object doesn't have the description. You have to explicitly call `app.get_chat()` to get the `Chat.bio` or `Chat.description`.

> `bio` (`str`, optional) – Bio of the other party in a private chat. Returned only in `get_chat()`.
>
> `description` (`str`, optional) – Description, for groups, supergroups and channel chats. Returned only in `get_chat()`.
>
> https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/Chat